# Print indentations with whitespace only in tree command

Tags: sed, tree

I want to list the subdirectories of a directory using `tree` command. But I don't want to print indentation lines. I only want to have the whitespaces instead.

I couldn't find the correct parameter in man page. Maybe I can pipe the output of `tree` to `sed` to remove the lines.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you want something like this:

```
tree | sed 's/├\|─\|│\|└/ /g'
```

It replaces all those "line" characters with spaces.

---

See:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── file1
│   └── file2
└── dir2
    ├── file1
    └── file2

2 directories, 4 files
$ tree | sed 's/├\|─\|│\|└/ /g'
.
    dir1
        file1
        file2
    dir2
        file1
        file2

2 directories, 4 files
```

Comment: This `sed` expression does not appear to work in Mac OS X.

Comment: Doesn't works for me as well

Comment: Was this meant to be extended regular expressions? Then it shiould be `sed -E`, but still the graphical characters seem wrong.

Answer (score 3):

It works:

```
tree | sed -e 's/[├──└│]/ /g'
```

Comment: This looks very similar to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/245416/117549) by chaos; can you explain why yours is better?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Because this one actually works, I guess. This replaces each character in the collection with a whitespace, while the one of chaos seems to replace something that doesn't even appear in `tree` output.

Comment: Maybe the terminal representation changed, or something else changed in the intervening ... 5+ years. They just looked like very similar characters to me. Indeed, using my browser to search for each character, I find them matched between the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the `-i` flag to your `tree` command to not display the indentations.  A bit simpler than piping to sed!

Comment: It looks like the author is trying to have each line of output prefixed by whitespace, rather than e.g. `├──` (though it's a bit ambiguously phrased).  `-i` removes all prefixes, so you can't really tell what the tree structure is.

Comment: This removes the folder names as well.

Answer (score 0):

Another (`sed`-free) way would be

```
tree | iconv -f utf8 -c -t latin1 | tr '\240' ' '
```

Here I convert the output from utf8 to latin1 (i.e. ISO-8859-1, ASCII would be also an option but I want to preserve some "Umlauts"). The `-c` option of `iconv` "*silently discards characters that cannot be converted*". Lastly, I remove non-breaking spaces. This might not be relevant to you.

**Caveat**: you loose UTF-8 encoded chars if they cannot be converted to your target encoding.